# IBM Integration Bus crashes

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

I'm a newbie and installed the IIB 10.0.0.11 developer version on Redhat 7.4, 4GB memory as root.
Following a simple Youtube tutorial IIB:

- iib toolkit (as root)
- cut & paste MQ input node: ok
- cut & paste MQ output node or any other action so far: crash

Error message (looks like Java problem):

```
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Xmnx64m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
```

Complete message:

[image]

Comment: can i email the image to you, it‘s too much text

Comment: You can just copy and past it into the question, select edit to do this.  You can highlight it after pasting and select the `{}` icon to have it keep the same format.  This also helps future people to search and find your question if they are receiving the same error.  Images are useful in a post, but make sure the post is still clear without them. If you post images of **code or error messages**, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

Comment: That just looks like Java memory and garbage collection settings, but is not a error.

Comment: while I‘m familiar wih the concept of gc I‘m not sure what I could be doing right now, would appreciate any advise

Comment: Yeah, there is no error message in the post or screenshot. While viewing those settings could be very helpful when we have an error message, they don't really do a lot of good on their own. That being said, I will give some anecdotal advice. Use more memory. Where I work, we have had trouble with only 4GB of RAM on our IIB machines, so now we do a minimum of 8GB. Also, your settings limit you to using only 1GB of RAM, regardless of how much is actually free. I recommend first increasing your memory settings to what is free, then maybe even increase the machine's RAM from there.

Comment: increasing the RAM isn‘t a problem as I‘m running it on IBM Cloud fka Softlayer. I increased it to 8gb, same error. which memory setting do I have to change? thx

Comment: Ah, sorry for the late response; I didn't realize I don't get notified about updates on questions I have activity on (there is probably a setting for that somewhere that I need to find). The "-xmx1024m" tells the toolkit to use no more than 1GB of memory. I don't know where the sweet spot is, but I'm fairly positive our toolkits were configured to use more than that. The "-XX:PermSize=256mb" _could_ also be a problem (and may have been something we modified too).
We need a proper error message to help though. https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F

Comment: On which environment are you using the toolkit ? If I'm correct, you need the MQ libraries to handle these nodes, so it might be part of the problem. In addition, my toolkits are always configured up to 2Go of ram, if it can help ;)